# How good are the anti-reflective coatings/covers that are available for netbooks?

Tags: netbook, anti-glare

My girlfriend's dad is buying her a netbook for Christmas and she doesn't want one with a reflective screen, but her old man has his heart set on buying a particular Acer model (can't remember which one) that has a SuperBright blah blah reflective screen.

How effective are the after-market covers/coatings that are available? Do they significantly reduce the quality of a screen? Are they comparable to having just bought a netbook with a non-glare screen in the first place?

Obviously the ideal choice would be "just get one that has an anti-glare screen to start off with", but this choice is out of our hands now so I'd appreciate help from anyone with any experience of such things!

Does anyone have any good recommendations?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

They are rubbish - Don't get one! I have never seen a good one that doesn't annoy the end user.

I have seen two main types, snap on - horrible and user gets fed up of using after a while or the plastic layer - almost impossible to apply without some sort of air bubbles.

I recommend that your girlfriend just trys to get on and uses it. I felt the same when I got my reflective screen, however, once it is on, you get used to it and it isn't really a problem at all... I like it! Two nights ago on the train, whilst waiting for it to boot, I used it as a mirror!!

Comment: Ah, that's why girls so often have laptops with reflective screens :-)

Comment: @Johannes, Thanks :(!... calling me a girl!!!